# Webdriver and firefox changes http://localhost/ to http://localhost.com/ - why?

Tags: firefox, windows-7, webdriver

I'm running the following on Win7 with Java6 and Firefox with webdriver:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://locahost/");
```

Instead of opening my local server this opens http://www.localhost.com/ which is a registered domain on the internet.

Why is webdriver doing this?

How can I fix this in a way that doesn't involve changing my hosts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no server at `locahost:80` (because of the typo?). If a host name has been entered into the location bar and doesn't resolve then Firefox will try to "fix it". This behavior is controlled by the preferences `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` (by default `true`), `browser.fixup.alternate.prefix` (by default `www.`) and `browser.fixup.alternate.suffix` (by default `.com`). Webdriver allows changing Firefox preferences via `FirefoxProfile.setPreference()` so you can disable this behavior - or simply fix the typo.